# Why does the control always redirects to index.php in php?

Tags: php

Sounds silly but I have this simple doubt i have a file structure as below

```
-->Client-login
--->index.php
--->default.php
```

but whenever i try to run the client-login from browser it always ends up reaching index.php?
What is the reason? Can any one answer me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `index.php` is set up as the default index page for directories in most (if not all) Apache installations. If you want `default.php` to be shown you can add the following snippet to an .htaccess file in that directory:

```
DirectoryIndex default.php index.php
```

The DirectoryIndex directive sets the list of resources or file to look for, when the client requests an index of the directory by specifying a / at the end of a directory name. It will serve the first resource it finds (i.e. that exists) in the list provided.